# handlebar compilation errors

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

Hi I have been trying to use backbonejs and handlebar templates but seems like either my jSON is wrong or data is not properly parse . Getting

```
Uncaught Error: You must pass a string to Handlebars.compile. You passed undefined
```

Code can be found at

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulL/T5v4z/1/)

any advice will be appreciated

Comment: Looks like you're missing a "#" in your template each statement; it should be `{{#each propertiesABC}}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your fiddle is broken in various ways but the odds are that you're doing this:

```
template: Handlebars.compile($('#tpl-page-list-item').html()),
```

before there is a `#tpl-page-list-item` available. This will happen if your page looks like:

```
<script src="your_backbone_javascript.js"></script>
<script id="tpl-page-list-item" ...></script>
```

as your Backbone view will be parsed before `<script id="tpl-page-list-item">` gets added to the DOM. You can wrap your Backbone views in a document-ready handler (with proper namespacing to account for the function wrapper):

```
$(function() {
    window.PageListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: Handlebars.compile($('#tpl-page-list-item').html()),
        //...
    });
});
```

or compile the template when instantiating your view:

```
initialize: function() {
    // Or check if it is in the prototype and put the compiled template
    // in the prototype if you're using the view multiple times...
    this.template = Handlebars.compile($('#tpl-page-list-item').html());
    //...
}
```

Comment: thanks! seems like that is one of the issue but I have been experimenting with another piece of code which works fine

http://jsfiddle.net/paulL/cTEBd/

Comment: Did you notice that the "onLoad" option is set in the sidebar of your fiddle? Switch that to "No wrap - <head>" and it'll break things.

Comment: ah right ...thanks! though onLoad on my other piece of code still do not resolve the issue...
http://jsfiddle.net/paulL/T5v4z/2/

Comment: Perhaps you should open your JavaScript console so that you can see what the problem is.